# How to use CASE WHEN in FIRST_VALUE Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

If I case when then select it by first_value saparately then it works, but it I combine First_value(case when ....) then it not work althought the code still run without syntax error

My try, I want to find latest overdue date, it only show null

> ```
>                     FIRST_VALUE(
>             CASE
>                 WHEN inv.aging_period = 0
>                      AND is_tad_paid = 0
>                      AND is_mad_paid = 0
>                      AND inv.min_amount_due > 0 THEN
>                     inv.due_date
>                 ELSE
>                     NULL
>             END
>         )
>         OVER(PARTITION BY inv.account_id
>              ORDER BY inv.DUE_DATE DESC NULLS LAST
>         )                      AS latest_overdue_date,
> ```

If I try this saparately, it works:

> ```
> select sub.*,  first_value(ALL_OVER_DUE_DAY) over (partition by account_id order by ALL_OVER_DUE_DAY desc nulls last) as latest_over_due2
>
> from (select 
>                 CASE
>                     WHEN inv.aging_period = 0
>                          AND is_tad_paid = 0
>                          AND is_mad_paid = 0
>                          AND inv.min_amount_due > 0 THEN
>                         inv.due_date
>                     ELSE
>                         NULL
>                 END AS ALL_OVER_DUE_DAY from t1 ) SUB
> ```

sample data, my resul column is the last column

[image]

Comment: I strongly suggest that you add sample table data here which helps to explain your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have added one

Comment: Please provide sample data **as text** and the entire`select` statement that "works". I suspect that you order by the calculated column, while in the "wrong" statement you order by original date.

Comment: @astentx I have add full statement that work, even I `order by inv.due_date desc`  or serial_number it still show null result

Comment: You may also replace `first_value` with `max` without change of `order by` because each overdue date is less than or equal to the invoice date

Comment: @HaoHao your previous comment is not true: first_value(ALL_OVER_DUE_DAY) over (partition by account_id order by **ALL_OVER_DUE_DAY** desc nulls last) as latest_over_due2. This is the reason

Comment: @astentx yes, I mean it's still due date

Comment: @astentx it worked with max(case when..) but why first_value not work?

Comment: @HaoHao because you order by different date and receive nulls. You may also use `first_value( ... ignore nulls)` with the same ordering as in your current query to get the same result

Comment: @astentx nice, but even I use over(....nulls last) but it not work with this?

Comment: You order by **different** date which doesn't have nulls where the calculated expression does

Comment: @astentx what u mean by `different date`? so in this case, Which column I should use in order by ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace First_value with MAX(), add unbounded preceeding... like bellow

```
                    max(
            CASE
                WHEN inv.aging_period = 0
                     AND is_tad_paid = 0
                     AND is_mad_paid = 0
                     AND inv.min_amount_due > 0 THEN
                    inv.due_date
                ELSE
                    NULL
            END
        )
        OVER(PARTITION BY inv.account_id
             ORDER BY inv.DUE_DATE DESC NULLS LAST
         ROWS BETWEEN
         UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
         AND
         UNBOUNDED following
        )
```